# Python 3 unescape \"

Tags: string, python-3.x, escaping

I want to have a string variable to store a value that has `\"` in it.

Example:

```
a = 'attribute=\"something\"'
```

with this exact value, not

```
a = 'attribute="something"'
```

I've tried with `'\\"'` even `'\\\\"'`.

I want to store the value in a variable, not to print it like this.

I'm trying to search and replace `attribute=\"something\"` to `old-attribute=\"something\"`. But I can't manage to create the value and replace variables.

I'm trying to store '\"' in a string variable:

```
>>> b ='\"'
>>> b
'"'

>>> b = '\\"'
>>> b
'\\"'

>>> b = '\\\"'
>>> b
'\\"'

>>> b = '\\\\"'
>>> b
'\\\\"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a raw string (note the `r`):

```
a = r'attribute=\"something\"'
print(a)
# attribute=\"something\"
```

If you look at `repr(a)` you will see the escaped version:

```
print(repr(a))
# 'attribute=\\"something\\"'
```

**EDIT**

I saw that you actually try to have `\"` as a string. Well, the same logic applies:

```
a = r'\"'
print(a)
# \"
print(repr(a))
# '\\"'
```

Comment: thank you. 

I actually wanted  
     repr(a) = '\"'
I thought I needed this , but it worked with repr(a) = '\\"'